# Is it possible to develop a real time data acquisition system in Windows XP with microsecond time precision?

Tags: java, windows, real-time

For one of my projects I need to develop a software which needs to acquire 2000 data in 100 millisecond from a parallel port after receiving a trigger from the application. It means the parallel port needs to be read in 50 micro second interval. Data frequency is set to 10 KHz. So, this acquisition process should be in real time with microsecond time precision.
I am trying to program in Java. So far I have been able to acquire data from the parallel port but struggling hard to maintain the time interval.
My question is: Is it really possible to do it under windows xp environment with such time (in microsecond) precision? If yes, can you please point me to some guidelines/resources?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: real time data acquistion is always going to be difficult in a garbage collected language unless you carefully manage memory...

Comment: I think you can come close to doing that only in a kernel-mode driver. And even then System Management (Mode) Interrupts (SMIs) may ruin the timing because they're completely transparent to the OS and are handled in the BIOS.

Comment: hi guys, thanx for the answers!
@Alex: Do u think  its possible to come close to what i want to achieve by writing a kernel mode driver and acquire the data and store it in a buffer  and then use the data in my program?

Comment: @user644614: writing kernel-mode drivers is no easy matter and I'm not quite sure how to workaround the SMM/SMIs (I don't know what to disable in the OS and/or BIOS to prevent them).

Comment: @Alex: thanks for the insights.

Comment: Interrupts CAN be disabled by using asm instructions cli/sti. Of course this falls under the "stupid things to do" because it will put the stability at risk. Furthermore interrupts ARE NOT transparrent to the OS due to the fact that the OS itself installs the ISR into the IDT so the code there is custom, and in fact it is possible to HOOK the IDT (at least on win x32 for Vista and upwards) for older version - it is also possible.

Comment: @LordDoskias - can you please explain a bit more how i can stop interruption from other services during data acquisition period and then enable again after acquisition is done? in the original code of the program which was written for DOS , i can see two function disable() and enable(). disable() is called just before starting of the data acquisition loop and enable() is called at the end of data acquisition. Is there anything like this i  can implement in windows xp/vista/7 with JAVA?

Comment: From java you most cerainly CANNOT disable interrupts, sorry if I was misleading you. What I would suggest is check this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-rtj1/ or just switch to a kernel-mode driver also check this as back reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838597%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It depends on if your software has to work reliably or just in most cases.

With a normal Java VM, you cannot predict the garbage collector behaviour, so you basically have no means to prevent the VM from interrupting the execution of your software for any arbitrary period of time.

There are possibilities to implement real time software in Java using a VM with extensions for the "Real-Time Specification for Java" (JSR-1), but AFAIK there are no implementations for Windows, since Windows itself has no real time capabilities. The former reference implementation from Sun (now maintained by Oracle) runs on Solaris and RT enabled Linux versions and there are other implementations for embedded systems.

Comment: thanks for your comment! well.. the software will be used for nerve conduction study(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_conduction_study) . so it has to be reliable in acquiring data. actually the original program is now working fine under dos operating system. my job is to modernize the program and develop the same thing for windows.
if its not possible to maintain micro second precision, at least i need to make sure there wont be any interruption while taking those 2000 data.

Answer (score 0):

System.nanoTime() even returns the time in nanosecond time precision, you can use it for microseconds as well.

Comment: But that won't solve the problem of missing data sampling instants.

Comment: Alex is right. its of not much help as long as u cant make sure other windows process aren't interrupting during data acquisition period.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not committed to doing this exclusively with Windows, it might be effective to add some additional hardware.  Although the hardware could be as elaborate as an FPGA, you might be able to do it with something as simple as 8-bit microcontroller, such as the Atmega328 used in the Arduino boards and IDE.  With that, you could sample the input, buffer the data, and drive the parallel port to the PC, with the microcontroller acting as a FIFO between the real-time data source and the close-to-real-time PC data consumption.

The Atmega328 has only 2K of RAM, so you would need to determine if that is enough to cover the PC's dead times.  If not, there are similar microcontrollers with larger RAM.

The Arduino UNO is available for

In case you are unfamiliar with microcontrollers, there is no OS under the skin that introduces uncertainly.  There are not system issues being maintained "invisibly".  Writing code is more like writing a kernel driver (in that you need be aware of real-time considerations, interrupt processing, and maintaining the integrity of the CPU state), but the surrounding system is as simple as possible.

-- Carl

Answer (score 0):

There are third party realtime extensions for Windows. Here's one: http://www.directinsight.co.uk/products/venturcom/rtx.html

They claim they deliver hard real time. Now, whether Java is appropriate for realtime programming to begin with is a big hard question. There's garbage collection, JIT compilation might get in the way... I'd say - stick to native code for the time critical parts (signal collection), build an interface to Java for the pretty GUI.

C++ is quite different from Java conceptually, but at least the syntax is close.

The RTX guys explicitly position themselves as an alternative to custom hardware, claim Intel CPUs on commodity motherboards can deliver realtime processing. Their stuff is not free though. You want free, go with an embedded flavor of Linux. Or with [QNX](http://www.qnx.com/).